# Symfony2 array access in twig error

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I don't know what is going on but here is my predicament:
When I want to access nested arrays in twig I get this error

> Impossible to access an attribute ("path") on a integer variable ("10977") in KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig at line 12

Now here is my twig code:

```
{% if flag == 0 or flag == 1 %}
    {% set width = 230 %}
    {% set height = 154 %}
{% elseif flag == 2 %}
    {% set width = 60 %}
    {% set height = 60 %}
{% endif %}

{% for artCats in articles %}
  {% for artCat in artCats %}
    {% set img_url = globalimagepath ~ "articles/" ~ artCat.path %}
    {% set cid = artCat.cid %}
    {% set catname = artCat.name %}
    {% set aPath = path('article_details', {'id': artCat.id, 'catname': catname|pathauto,  'title': artCat.title|pathauto}) %}
     <li>
        <article>
            {% if loop.first %}
            {% if flag == 0 or flag == 1 %}
              <h3><a href="{{ path('category_details', {'id': cid, 'name': catname|pathauto}) }}">{{ catname|teaser(28) }}</a></h3>
            {% endif %}
            {% if flag != 3 %}<a href="{{ aPath }}"><img src="{{ image('http://'~ app.request.getHttpHost() ~ asset(img_url)).zoomCrop(width,height).jpeg }}" alt="{{ artCat.title }}"></a>{% endif %}
                <h1><a href="{{ aPath }}">{{ artCat.title|teaser(79) }}</a></h1>
            {% else %}
                <h2><a href="{{ path('article_details', {'id': artCat.id, 'catname': artCat.name|pathauto,  'title': artCat.title|pathauto}) }}">{{ artCat.title|teaser(37) }}</a></h2>
            {% endif %}
            </article>
      </li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And here is my debug of the variable articles in twig:

```
array(4) {
  ["Zdravlje općenito"]=&gt;
  array(11) {
    [0]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(11659)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(36) "Brinete li o zdravlju svojih očiju?"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1330007101_516.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [1]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(14663)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(29) "Otkrijte uzročnike alergija!"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1380196476_342.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [2]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(14664)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(24) "Uzroci bolova u kukovima"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1380195386_853.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [3]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(14665)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(13) "Napadi panike"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1380195261_180.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [4]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(11170)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(28) "Čaj od ružmarina kao lijek"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1380116708_577.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [5]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(10970)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(35) "Začinite i produžite svoj život!"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1380031350_101.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [6]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(11171)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(32) "Meditacijom do punine življenja"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1380103969_112.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [7]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(10973)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(20) "Zašto volimo cimet?"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1379579290_899.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [8]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(10977)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(32) "Simptomi hormonalne neravnoteže"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1379507943_927.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [9]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(10978)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(46) "Čaj od đumbira - ukusni napitak koji liječi"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1379419241_320.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
    [10]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(10979)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(24) "Zašto volimo ružmarin?"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1379335723_831.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(266)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
    }
  }
  ["Izgled i ljepota"]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    [0]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(14662)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(20) "Joga za mršavljenje"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1380198181_298.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(268)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(16) "Izgled i ljepota"
    }
    [1]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(10971)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(32) "Najbolja prehrana za vašu kožu"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1379939148_517.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(268)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(16) "Izgled i ljepota"
    }
    [2]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(10974)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(30) "Najčešći uzročnici rosacee"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1379579025_722.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(268)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(16) "Izgled i ljepota"
    }
  }
  ["Seks i veze"]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [0]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(10975)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(19) "10 mitova o orgazmu"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1379578683_758.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(270)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(11) "Seks i veze"
    }
  }
  ["Sport i rekreacija"]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [0]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(10976)
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(41) "Što se događa s tijelom kada vježbate?"
      ["path"]=&gt;
      string(18) "1379577938_298.jpg"
      ["cid"]=&gt;
      int(271)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Sport i rekreacija"
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason I can't access any of the variables in the nested array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Impossible to access an attribute ("path") on a integer variable
>   ("10977") in
>   KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig at line 12

Do you get the error only with the 8th element in the array (the one with id 10977)?  Do the iterations work before reaching that element ?

Comment: Ok sry to all the people because I just figured out I'm semi retarded :(. I used the same template for different types of results on the same index page. Actually everything was ok with this part I posted in the question, the error was in another block on my index site that used the same template but passed a normal array not a nested one :(. Sry for wasting everybody's time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is failing: `{% set img_url = globalimagepath ~ "articles/" ~ artCat.path %}`

Do `{{ dump(artCat) }}`. It seems to be an integer instead of array/object.

Comment: I posted the dump(articles). The artCat is inside the articles array. The problem is not in the path variable, if I put artCat.id I still get the same error but insted Impossible to access an attribute ("path") i get Impossible to access an attribute ("id")

Comment: Did you try dumping that `artCat` inside loop ?

Comment: Yes, all of the data is there here is one artCat: array(5) {
  ["id"]=&gt;
  int(11659)
  ["title"]=&gt;
  string(36) "Brinete li o zdravlju svojih očiju?"
  ["path"]=&gt;
  string(18) "1330007101_516.jpg"
  ["cid"]=&gt;
  int(266)
  ["name"]=&gt;
  string(18) "Zdravlje općenito"
}

Comment: This is even funnier, when I put artCat[0] instead artCat.path I get this error: Key "0" for array with keys "id, title, path, cid, name" does not exist in KprCentarZdravljaBundle:Parts:articleDefaultBlock.html.twig at line 13 - So funny because the system knows its an array and what are the array keys, but when i try to access one I cant :(