# Accessing attribute on string variable error in twig

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, twig

I have written some code for a password reset function. At the moment I generate a token and send a link with a url containing the token for the user to visit, and reset their password. The issue I am having is that I get the error when trying to follow the link that is sent to the user for the confirm new password part;

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("email") on a string variable ("someemail@gmail.com") in "confirm-new-password.twig" at line 45
```

I have a function in my model that checks whether the timestamp for the token has expired or not as show below. If has expired return null otherwise it should return the values for the email and token stored in an array so that it can be used in the twig template in order to process the form;

```
    public function get_token($email,$token){
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->link, $email);
      $token = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->link, $token);

      $result = mysqli_query($this->link, "select email, token, expirytime from user where email = '{$email}'");

      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

      $time = strtotime($row['expirytime']);

      $curtime = time();
      $userResetDets = array($row['email'],$row['token']);
      if($token === $row['token'] && (($curtime-$time)  < 60)){
        return $userResetDets;
      }else{
        $res = mysqli_query($this->link,"update user set token='' and expirytime='' where email = '{$email}'");
        return null;
      }

  }
```

in my controller I have the following code;

```
$app->get('/confirm-new-password/{email}/{token}', function($email,$token) use($app) {
$test = $app['auth']->get_token($email,$token);


if (null !== $test){
    return $app['twig']->render('confirm-new-password.twig', array('active_page' => 'confirm-new-password', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'items' => $app['tutor']->get_user_id(), 'test' => $test));
}else{
    return $app->redirect('/');
}

});
```

and in my twig file I have the following;

```
<form class="form-signin" action="/confirm-new-password" method="post">
<h2 class="form-heading">Confirm New Password</h2>
<label for="inputNewPass1" class="sr-only">New Password</label>
<input type="password" id="inputNewPass1" class="form-control" name="pass1" placeholder="New Password" required>
<label for="inputNewPass2" class="sr-only">Re-Type New Password</label>
<input type="password" id="inputNewPass2" class="form-control" name="pass2" placeholder="Re-type New Password" required>
{% for items in test %}

<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ items.email }}">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ items.token }}">
{% endfor %}
<div class="spamCheck">
    <label for="inputPostcode" class=sr-only">Postcode</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputPostcode" class="form-control" name="postcode" placeholder="Leave this field blank" />
</div>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" type="submit">Reset Password</button>
```

also in my model I have the function to get the primary key in order to loop through the array variables in twig file;

```
public function get_user_id(){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, 'select email from user');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        foreach($row as $item){
            $items = $item;
        }
    }
}
```

However I get the error above when I try to run this code. I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376701/impossible-to-access-an-attribute-username-on-a-null-variable) and tried to follow the instructions as mentioned by changing my `forloop` within the twig file to this;

```
  {% if test %}

        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ test.email }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ test.token }}">

 {% endif %}
```

then I get the error;

```
Key "email" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist in "confirm-new-password.twig" at line 45
```

I also had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045905/symfony2-array-access-in-twig-error) and changed the `forloop` again to;

```
  {% if test is defined %}

        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ test.email }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ test.token }}">

 {% endif %}
```

but get the same error;

```
Key "email" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist in "confirm-new-password.twig" at line 45
```

I also had a look at [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9683/impossible-to-access-an-attribute-title-on-a-string-variable) but got an error as well again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
$userResetDets = array($row['email'],$row['token']);
```

Creates an array with 2 elements, at indices `0` and `1`, but you are trying to use it like an associative array later. Change it to this:

```
$userResetDets = array(
  'email' => $row['email'],
  'token' => $row['token']
);
```